# How to accelerate speech recognition to control an animation in WPF/.NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, speech-recognition

I have build a c#/WPF test application using an animation and speech recognition to control the animation.

It works correct but after saying something the animation runs approx for half a second respectively some pixels.

Because I am trying to develop something for neurological patients it should stop immediately.

Is there a way maybe by rearranging the code to speed up the recognition process.

Or is it faster to work with the extern speech recognition of Windows OS?

The following code runs on a Windows 8, x64 machine. Intel Core i7 Quadcore. 2.40 MHz. 8 GB RAM.

Thanks in advance!

```
[...]


private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    imgRed.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, new Screen().HeightHalf);
    imgBlue.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, new Screen().HeightHalf);

    Screen scr = new Screen();
    sb = new Storyboard();

    Duration dur10sek = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));

    // Red circle animation
    daRed = new DoubleAnimation();
    daRed.To = scr.WidthHalf - imgBlue.Width + 4;
    daRed.Duration = dur10sek;
    sb.Children.Add(daRed);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(daRed, "imgRed");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daRed, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));

    // Blue circle animation
    daBlue = new DoubleAnimation();
    daBlue.To = scr.WidthHalf - imgBlue.Width + 4;
    daBlue.Duration = dur10sek;

    sb.Children.Add(daBlue);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(daBlue, "imgBlue");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daBlue, new PropertyPath(Canvas.RightProperty));

    //sb.Begin(imgRed, true);
    sb.Begin(imgBlue, true);

    // Speech recognition
    sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    var controls = new Choices();
    controls.Add(new SemanticResultValue("stop", "STOP"));
    controls.Add(new SemanticResultValue("weiter", "WEITER"));

    GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(controls);


    sre.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));
    sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sprache_erkannt);
}

// Speech to stop animation
void sprache_erkannt(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) {

    const double ConfidenceTreshold = 0.3;

    if (e.Result.Confidence >= ConfidenceTreshold){

        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "stop":
                sb.Pause(imgBlue);
                break;
            case "weiter":
                sb.Resume(imgBlue);
                break;
        }

    }

}

[...]
```

Comment: You can try external speech recognition engine, which might be more configurable than default one.